# Listar pasta com arquivos com extensão htm e abrir em nova página

Tags: php-5

Diariamente recebo arquivos com extensão em ".htm" com informações que preciso abrir para visualizar e, sempre uso o recurso botão da direita do mouse e 'abrir com' e escolho o navegador.
Assim:
arquivotexto1.htm
arquivotexto2.htm
arquivotexto3.htm

Detalhe: os nomes dos arquivos variam sempre, mas a extensão é sempre '.htm'

---

tentei fazer este código:

```
<?php
// diretório onde estão os arquivos
$diretorio = "c:\diretorio\mes_e_Ano";

// *.txt são os formatos de arquivos a serem alterados
foreach (glob("$diretorio/*.*") as $arquivo) {
$p1 = explode("/", $arquivo);
$p2 = explode(".", $p1[1]);
//print "<a href=\"$arquivo\" target=\"_blank\">$p2[0]</a><br>";
//print "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('$arquivo','_blank','')\">$p2[0]</a><br>";
print "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('http://nomeservidor/mes_e_ano/','$arquivo','')\">$p2[0]</a><br>";
}

?>
```

até abre a visualização dos arquivos. Consigo visualizar.
Mas quando clico nos mesmos, apresenta erro que não existe visualização. 'Forbidden'

se alterar o parâmetro no servidor, no "Options -Indexes" , colocando um "#" na frente ele passa a exibir e funciona, porém o correto é manter o parâmetro por questões de segurança pelo que tive observando.

Gostaria de saber como faço para no momento em que clicar no 'link' simbólico, já abra automaticamente, sem precisar desativar o parâmetro.

Se alguém puder auxiliar, agradeço

Comment: Abre direto o arquivo no window.open assim: window.open('http://nomeservidor/mes_e_ano/$arquivo')

Comment: ola! agradeço retorno!
No caso, fiz desta forma agora:

Comment: ola! agradeço retorno! Obrigado!
No caso, fiz esta alteração(linha) desta forma agora:
----
('http://nome_servidor:porta/mes_e_ano/$arquivo','')\">$p2[0]</a><br>";
}
-----
Exibe uma mensagem assim, após clicar no nome do link , no caso 0109.htm:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /mês e_ano/c:diretoriomes_e_ano/0109.htm on this server.

se eu digitar direto a seguinte linha no navegador:
http://nome_servidor:porta/mes_e_ano/0109.htm => abre normalmente sem problemas
Deve estar faltando algo no código.
aguardo se alguém puder auxiliar.

Comment: Cara... dessa forma, o erro não está na programação e sim no caminho que o PHP está montando. Verifica isso.

Comment: bom dia! notei que na variável '$arquivo', está vindo o caminho completo e, não somente o nome do arquivo. Pode ser isso. Não achei ainda a forma correta de fazer o apontamento. alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Use a função scandir ao invés do GLOB, pode resolver!
$arquivos=scandir($diretorio);
foreach($arquivos as $arquivo){ ... }

Comment: ola! agradeço e farei a mudança para scandir.
Ainda na outra forma original, fiz assim e, funcionou. Pela dica que deu sobre o caminho, mudei os parâmetros de acesso da posição do vetor. Muito Obrigado! Agora acessou:
______
<?php
// diretório onde estão os arquivos
$diretorio = "c:\nomePasta\mes_e_ano";

// *.txt são os formatos de arquivos a serem alterados
foreach (glob("$diretorio/*.htm") as $arquivo) {
$p1 = explode("/", $arquivo);
$p2 = explode(".", $p1[1]);
print "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('http://nomeservidor:porta/mes_e_ano/$p1[1]','')\">$p2[0]</a><br>";
}

?>